# How to use JWT SSO/auto login with HumHub

Tags: php, yii, yii2, social-networking

Does anyone know a good example of use of JWTs with HumHub?

I found a starting point in the official documentation, but it does not explain clearly what should be send in the header or payload of the JWT to get the SSO/auto login working.

Is it the user id, the user email ... ?

Also, it looks like it is just for the enterprise edition, is there an example that is free to use?

Is there any other way to auto login in HumHub?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who doesn't know, you need enterprise installed for JWT to work. If you have the community edition installed you can install enterprise as a module. It will ask you for a license key which you can buy for 99 euros a month but if you ask their support desk nicely they will give you a trial license to play with :).

In `humhub/protected/modules/enterprise/modules/jwt/examples/php/index.php` there's some sample code that you can use for authenticating a user.

```
// Load JWT Libary
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Firebase\JWT\JWT;

// Configuration
$key = 'your shared key';
$domain = "http://humhub.example.com";
$urlRewritingEnabled = false;

// Build token including your user data
$now = time();
$token = array(
    'iss' => 'example',
    'jti' => md5($now . rand()),
    'iat' => $now,
    'exp' => $now + 60,
    'username' => 'j.doe',
    'firstname' => 'John',
    'lastname' => 'Doe',
    'email' => 'john.doe@example.com',
);

// Create JWT token
$jwt = JWT::encode($token, $key);

// Redirect user back to humhub
if ($urlRewritingEnabled) {
    $location = $domain . '/user/auth/external?authclient=jwt';
} else {
    $location = $domain . '/index.php?r=/user/auth/external&authclient=jwt';
}
$location .= "&jwt=" . $jwt;

header("Location: " . $location);
```

So what I did was I copied this code to my own PHP file e.g. https://test.example.com/jwtclient.php and then in humhub/protected/config/common.php I added this:

```
return [
    // ...
    'components' => [
        // ...
        'authClientCollection' => [
            'clients' => [
                // ...
                'jwt' => [
                    'class' => 'humhub\modules\enterprise\modules\jwt\authclient\JWT',
                    'url'       => 'https://test.example.com/jwtclient.php',
                    'sharedKey' => 'your shared key', // same as jwtclient.php
                    // Other configuration options
                    'title' => 'Company SSO Login',
                    // Automatic login, when allowed IP matches
                    'autoLogin' => true,
                    // Limit allowed JWT IPs
                    // 'allowedIPs' => ['localhost'],
                    // Leeway (seconds) for token validation
                    'leeway' => 60
                ]
            ]
        ]
        // ...
    ]
    // ...
];
```

And what will happen is that if you go to humhub.example.com it will redirect to test.example.com/jwtclient.php and redirect back to humhub.example.com with the jwt appended to the URL. This is how it works.

I also noticied that you don't need to use LDAP for this to work either. Just make sure your database users do not have a password in table `user_password`.

I hope this helps you as it was racking my brain as well!